# Why i'm getting two different values of $\log\left(\frac{1}{i^4}\right)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

$$\log\left(\frac{1}{i^4}\right)=\log\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)=\color{red}{\mathbf{0}}$$

**Another way**

$$\log\left(\frac{1}{i^4}\right)=4\log\left(\frac{1}{i}\right)=4\log\left(\frac{i^3}{i^4}\right)=
4\log\left(\frac{i^3}{1}\right)
=4\log[\cos(\pi/2)+i\sin(\pi/2)]^3=$$
$$4\log[\cos(3\pi/2)+i\sin(3\pi/2)]=4\log e^{3\pi/2}=4\times 3\pi/2=\color{red}{\mathbf {6 \pi i}}$$

Why am I getting different results?

Comment: Note that $4\times \frac{3\pi}{2}=6\pi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about it? If $z\neq0$ and $w$ is a logarithm of $z$, then *every* number of the form $w+2n\pi i$ ($n\in\mathbb Z$) is a logarithm of $z$.

Answer (score 2):

Rectified version of **Another way**:

$$\ln\left(\dfrac1i\right)^4=4\ln\dfrac1i=4\ln(i^3)=4\ln e^{i3\pi /2}=6\pi$$

Actually $$\ln(a+ib)$$ is  a multi valued function, the princial value is determined by [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation)